# Google Analytics: track referral sites when secondary domain redirects to primary domain

Tags: google-analytics

I have a client who has a few domains that are all redirected (via DNS settings) to his primary domain. Is there a way that we can monitor the traffic from these other domains in Google Analytics?

Scenario
User clicks on a link on referral.com and goes to domainA.com which is redirected to domainB.com. GA is tracking domainB.com. Currently domainA.com is listed as a referral site, we want to see referral.com listed instead.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You could retrieve via code the referral in domainA.com and then use the UTM parameters in the redirect link like:

```
domainB.com?utm_source=referral.com&utm_medium=referral
```

See here for more information about how generate custom campaign parameters:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en

Comment: Yes, I did see that, but as domainA has no hosting associated with it, the current redirection is via DNS (an A Record) so it's using an IP address to point to domainB. Can you point domainA to a subdomain on domainB, and then you can use htaccess to do the redirect and us utm? This is really not my area of expertise.

Comment: You can try to do as you say, if you just need to know the source and medium it can work. Consider that if you're talking about a website, too many redirects aren't a good SEO best practice.